# Get Specific Data from my xml with id?

Tags: jquery, xml

I have a script that gets my data from XML and append it my body tag as i wish.

Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $.get('myData.xml', function(d){
    $('body').append('<h1> Recommended Web Development Books </h1>');
    $('body').append('<dl />');

    $(d).find('country').each(function(){

        var $myapp = $(this); 
        var title = $myapp.attr("title");
        var currency = $myapp.attr("currency");
        var capitol = $myapp.attr("capitol");
        var popul = $myapp.attr("popul");
        var lang = $myapp.attr("lang");
        var phone = $myapp.attr("phone");
        var taxi = $myapp.attr("taxi");
        var airports = $myapp.attr("airports");


        var description = $myapp.find('description').text();
        var imageurl = $myapp.attr('imageurl');

        var html = '<dt> <img class="bookImage" alt="" src="' + imageurl + '" /> </dt>';
        html += '<dd> <span class="loadingPic" alt="Loading" />';
        html += '<p class="b-title">' + title + '</p>';
        html += '<p class="title"> Para Birimi</p> <p>' + currency + '</p>';
        html += '<p class="title"> Başkent</p><p> ' + capitol + '</p>' ;
        html += '<p class="title"> Nüfus</p><p> ' + popul + '</p>' ;
        html += '<p class="title"> Dil</p><p> ' + lang + '</p>' ;
        html += '<p class="title"> Telefon Kodu</p><p> ' + phone + '</p>' ;
        html += '<p class="title"> Taksi</p><p> ' + taxi + '</p>' ;
        html += '<p class="title"> Havalanları</p><p> ' + airports + '</p>' ;
        html += '<p class="title"> Ne Zaman Gidilir</p><p> ' + description + '</p>' ;
        html += '</dd>';

        $('dl').append($(html));

        $('.loadingPic').fadeOut(1400);
    });
});
```

When i click a link which has an id that gets the content from XML which same ID.

For example there is a Germany button and its ID is "01" when i click it i want see just Germany's data from my XML in a blank page or same page no matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the id to your `dl` list so that we know which country each `dt` and `dd` are. Then show just those two elements in the `dl` according to the `id` of the button clicked.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $.get('myData.xml', function(d){
    $('body').append('<h1> Recommended Web Development Books </h1>');
    $('body').append('<dl />');

    $(d).find('country').each(function(){

        var $myapp = $(this); 
        var title = $myapp.attr("title");
        var currency = $myapp.attr("currency");
        var capitol = $myapp.attr("capitol");
        var popul = $myapp.attr("popul");
        var lang = $myapp.attr("lang");
        var phone = $myapp.attr("phone");
        var taxi = $myapp.attr("taxi");
        var airports = $myapp.attr("airports");


        var description = $myapp.find('description').text();
        var imageurl = $myapp.attr('imageurl');
        var id = $myapp.attr('id');

        var html = '<dt class="' + id + '"> <img class="bookImage" alt="" src="' + imageurl + '" /> </dt>';
        html += '<dd class="' + id + '"> <span class="loadingPic" alt="Loading" />';
        html += '<p class="b-title">' + title + '</p>';
        html += '<p class="title"> Para Birimi</p> <p>' + currency + '</p>';
        html += '<p class="title"> Başkent</p><p> ' + capitol + '</p>' ;
        html += '<p class="title"> Nüfus</p><p> ' + popul + '</p>' ;
        html += '<p class="title"> Dil</p><p> ' + lang + '</p>' ;
        html += '<p class="title"> Telefon Kodu</p><p> ' + phone + '</p>' ;
        html += '<p class="title"> Taksi</p><p> ' + taxi + '</p>' ;
        html += '<p class="title"> Havalanları</p><p> ' + airports + '</p>' ;
        html += '<p class="title"> Ne Zaman Gidilir</p><p> ' + description + '</p>' ;
        html += '</dd>';

        $('dl').append($(html));

        $('.loadingPic').fadeOut(1400);
    });//end country.each

    $('input[id]').click(function() {
        $('dl > *').hide();
        $('dl .' + $(this).attr('id')).show();
    });//end input.click
    });//end $.get
});//end doc.ready
```

You can also switch `.hide()` and `.show()` with either `.fadeOut()` and `.fadeIn()` or `.slideUp()` and `.slideDown()`.

Answer (score 0):

Create htmlArray variable before each() and make it array (or JSON object)
Than in each() set every language as different array node like htmlArray['de']=html (if language is german) or something similar for JSON.
Set click event on button, when clicked then test language and use appropriate array node for that language.